# Alternative to substitute() or names() to keep data frame names with lapply

Tags: r

The set up: I have a bunch of data frames that I have read in. Each data frame is named after the company that supplied the data. I need a column that has the company name repeated over and over (it will be helpful when they all get merged), but some companies provided the names already while others did not.

I made a function to check if the column existed, and add it if it doesn't. I used `substitute()` in the function to get at the name of the data frame, since that's in some cases the only way to know what the name is. However, I wanted to use this function in `lapply()` because I read in all the files as a named list using `list.files()` and `lapply()`. When you run my new function through `lapply()` it actually gives something like index name of the data frame in the list. Here is my code:

```
none <- Negate(any) 

compName <- function(df){

 if(none(names(df) == "Company")){
   colEnd <- length(df) + 1
   name <- as.character(substitute(df))
   df[, colEnd] <- name
   colnames(df)[colEnd] <- "Company"

   return(df) 
  } 
}
```

So for instance, if you used the `iris` data frame with this function, you would get a column named Company with "iris" repeated over and over. However, if you made iris into a named list, it instead returns `"[[" "X"  "i"`?

```
iris_list <- list(iris, iris)
names(iris_list)[1] <- "iris"
names(iris_list)[2] <- "iris2"

iris_list2 <- lapply(iris_list, compName)
iris_list2[[1]][, 6] #To demonstrate the result
```

At this point I may just manually add the names of the companies to each file in Excel before import to R, but I have come this far trying to do it programmatically. I think I am missing some information about the fundamental characteristic of the data frame name, either within or outside of a list.

Comment: Should the result look like this: `setNames(lapply(seq(iris_list), function(x) transform(iris_list[[x]], Company=names(iris_list)[x])), names(iris_list))`?

Comment: Yes, exactly! There are a couple of functions here that are new to me (`setNames` and `transform`); the former seems especially magical for some reason? It will be good to read about it. If you put this as the answer I would accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can build up on this:

```
(res <- lapply(seq(iris_list), function(x) 
                                 transform(iris_list[[x]], Company=names(iris_list)[x])))

# [[1]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Company
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa    iris
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa    iris
# ...
# 
# [[2]]
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Company
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa   iris2
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa   iris2
# ...
```

Here, `lapply` iterates through an index `1:length(iris_list)` instead of the list elements directly. 
This way, you can access the names of the list elements more easily: `names(iris_list)[x]`. 
I used `transform` as a shortcut of `{ df <- iris_list[[x]]; df$Company=names(iris_list)[x]; return(df) }`. 
And `setNames` is a shortcut of `names(res) <- names(iris_list)` - as you can see, the `res` list lost the original names...

Comment: Thank you for the added explanation!

Comment: Slight alternative - `lapply(names(iris_list), function(x) cbind(iris_list[[x]], Company=x) )` or even `sapply(names(iris_list), function(x) cbind(iris_list[[x]], Company=x), USE.NAMES=TRUE, simplify=FALSE)` if you want to retain the names and the `list` structure.